# Mirror multiple select fields jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to JavaScript and HTML, and I want to achieve the following structure:

```
[Drop down 1]
               [Option 1]
               [Option 2]
[Drop down 2]
               [Option 1]
               [Option 2]
..and so on
```

Then I want the options reflected in TD's below like:

```
<td>&nbsp;</td><td class="sel1">Selected option from drop-down 1</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td><td class="sel2">Selected option from drop-down 2</td>
..and so on
```

**UPDATE:** Added Jfiddle as per request from Joshua Kisubi: https://jsfiddle.net/2ra5ptk1/1/

```css
td {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

select,
body {
  font-family: calibri;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  I need the selection from "Selection 1" to be outputted in the column to the right of "Results from selection 1" in the table below, and so on for each drop down. I don't know javascript or jQuery though, so I am not able to achieve this:<br><br>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection1">
                  <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
                  <option value="option2">Sel1: Option 1</option>
                  <option value="option1">Sel1: Option 2</option>
                </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection2">
                  <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
                  <option value="option2">Sel2: Option 1</option>
                  <option value="option1">Sel2: Option 2</option>
                </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection3">
                  <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
                  <option value="option2">Sel3: Option 1</option>
                  <option value="option1">Sel3: Option 2</option>
                </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection4">
                  <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
                  <option value="option2">Sel4: Option 1</option>
                  <option value="option1">Sel4: Option 2</option>
                </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection5">
                  <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
                  <option value="option2">Sel5: Option 1</option>
                  <option value="option1">Sel5: Option 2</option>
                </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection6">
                  <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
                  <option value="option2">Sel6: Option 1</option>
                  <option value="option1">Sel6: Option 2</option>
                </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection7">
                  <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
                  <option value="option2">Sel7: Option 1</option>
                  <option value="option1">Sel7: Option 2</option>
                </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection8">
                  <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
                  <option value="option2">Sel8: Option 1</option>
                  <option value="option1">Sel8: Option 2</option>
                </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection9">
                  <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
                  <option value="option2">Sel9: Option 1</option>
                  <option value="option1">Sel9: Option 2</option>
                </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection10">
                  <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
                  <option value="option2">Sel10: Option 1</option>
                  <option value="option1">Sel10: Option 2</option>
                </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection11">
                  <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
                  <option value="option2">Sel11: Option 1</option>
                  <option value="option1">Sel11: Option 2</option>
                </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection12">
                  <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
                  <option value="option2">Sel12: Option 1</option>
                  <option value="option1">Sel12: Option 2</option>
                </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 1:</td>
            <td class="sel1">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 2:</td>
            <td class="sel2">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 3:</td>
            <td class="sel3">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 4:</td>
            <td class="sel4">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 5:</td>
            <td class="sel5">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 6:</td>
            <td class="sel6">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 7:</td>
            <td class="sel7">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 8:</td>
            <td class="sel8">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 9:</td>
            <td class="sel9">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 10:</td>
            <td class="sel10">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 11:</td>
            <td class="sel11">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 12:</td>
            <td class="sel12">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Can anyone give me any tips or resources on how to achieve this result?

Comment: get the value from dropdown1 and insert it into sel1 and so on

Comment: Hi @JoshuaKisubi, yes, that's exactly what I need.

Comment: Yes do that. you have not provided valid html js so there is nothing I can do. provide the actual code preferably with jsfiddle

Comment: @JoshuaKisubi there, updated the question with https://jsfiddle.net/2ra5ptk1/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up the usage of id versus classes in your html so it is hard to reference in javascript. 
Use id for unique elements on a page and classes for similar ones. 
that way you can attach an event handler to select elements at once. 
Ofcourse you can have a for loop to attach to select with id `'sel'+ count` but that is inefficient.

```js
$(function() {
 $('.selection').on('change', function(){
  var sel_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var sel_opt = $(this).val();
    
  $('table td#'+sel_id).text(sel_opt)
 })
});
```

```css
td {
  font-family:calibri;
  font-size:14px;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

select, body {
    font-family:calibri;
  font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  I need the selection from "Selection 1" to be outputted in the column to the right of "Results from selection 1" in the table below, and so on for each drop down. I don't know javascript or jQuery though, so I am not able to achieve this:<br><br>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>

        Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection" data-id="sel1">
          <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
          <option value="option2">Sel1: Option 1</option>
          <option value="option1">Sel1: Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection" data-id="sel2">
          <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
          <option value="option2">Sel2: Option 1</option>
          <option value="option1">Sel2: Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection" data-id="sel3">
          <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
          <option value="option2">Sel3: Option 1</option>
          <option value="option1">Sel3: Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection" data-id="sel4">
          <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
          <option value="option2">Sel4: Option 1</option>
          <option value="option1">Sel4: Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection" data-id="sel5">
          <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
          <option value="option2">Sel5: Option 1</option>
          <option value="option1">Sel5: Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection" data-id="sel6">
          <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
          <option value="option2">Sel6: Option 1</option>
          <option value="option1">Sel6: Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection" data-id="sel7">
          <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
          <option value="option2">Sel7: Option 1</option>
          <option value="option1">Sel7: Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection" data-id="sel8">
          <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
          <option value="option2">Sel8: Option 1</option>
          <option value="option1">Sel8: Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection" data-id="sel9">
          <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
          <option value="option2">Sel9: Option 1</option>
          <option value="option1">Sel9: Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection" data-id="sel10">
          <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
          <option value="option2">Sel10: Option 1</option>
          <option value="option1">Sel10: Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection" data-id="sel11">
          <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
          <option value="option2">Sel11: Option 1</option>
          <option value="option1">Sel11: Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>Selection 1:<br>
        <select class="selection" data-id="sel12">
          <option value="choose">[Choose]</option>
          <option value="option2">Sel12: Option 1</option>
          <option value="option1">Sel12: Option 2</option>
        </select>

      </td><td>

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 1:</td><td id="sel1">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 2:</td><td id="sel2">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 3:</td><td id="sel3">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 4:</td><td id="sel4">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 5:</td><td id="sel5">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 6:</td><td id="sel6">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 7:</td><td id="sel7">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 8:</td><td id="sel8">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 9:</td><td id="sel9">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 10:</td><td id="sel10">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 11:</td><td id="sel11">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Result from selection 12:</td><td id="sel12">RESULT HERE</td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>
```

Comment: little nitpick - you can use `$(this).data('id');` instead of `$(this).attr('data-id');` https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/

Comment: Cool @JoshKisb! Very elegant, and I even understand the logic. I will be sure to remember it. Thank you!